# Loop over dates and count word per day with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a date frame with a column of dates Y-M-D and a column with text.

I would like to iterate over the rows and determine the frequency of specific words (pre-defined in a list) per day. Then this should go into a dictionary with the frequency of each word per day.

I have this to count words in a list

`words = ['monkey', 'cat']
pd.Series((df.text.str.contains(r).sum() for r in words), words, name='count')`

I have already created an index:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['1958-12-20', '1958-11-08', '1959-11-13', '1959-01-13',
             '1959-06-05', '1959-06-25', '1959-10-27', '1959-11-14',
             '1959-01-14', '1960-07-02',
             ...
             '1979-07-28', '1979-04-27', '1979-05-19', '1979-01-11',
             '1979-03-17', '1979-12-13', '1979-11-17', '1979-03-17',
             '1979-07-25', '1979-10-20'],
             dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4481, freq=None)
```

I know a little about groupby and iterrows, but I'm not sure how to combine this and put the output in a dictionary.